# Should I stop services when performing release upgrade?

Tags: mysql, postfix, do-release-upgrade

Should I stop services like `mysql` and `postfix` before performing release upgrade(from 18.04 to 20.04)? Is there a risk of data loss/corruption if I don't?

Comment: Refer https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FocalFossa/ReleaseNotes  where you'll note it's not a requirement. You maybe prompted to 'stop' services during the upgrade though (ie. follow the advice given which states "*Follow the on-screen instructions*").

Comment: Concern for your users' data is a good professional attitude. On a personal machine, it should not matter, since you are the only one mucking about with the data. On a multi-user system, scheduling the release-upgrade for least-impactful time-of-day, stopping data services, and then backing up data before starting a release-upgrade are all wise precautions.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need to do that. If an service is up and you upgrade they will be restarted automatically once they are done.